# Does JIT optimize divisions by one?

Tags: java, jit

Let's suppose that in a certain piece of code, sometimes happens that a division is using 1 as a divisor, this code is frequently called and is eligible for JIT compilation to native code.

Does JIT able to optimize the division by one in the generated assembly code?

Comment: Do you mean code like `x/1` or `x/y` where `y` could be 1 at runtime?

Comment: When you say "optimize the division by one", do you mean "omit"?

Comment: Given the other other optimizations performed by the JIT, I'd be amazed if it didn't; on the other hand, given the other optimizations performed by the JIT, I'd be amazed if the difference from this was significant.

Comment: I mean that a division by one is not necessary, then JIT could optimize this.

Comment: Note that `a / 1` isn't necessarily a no-op. For example `((Integer) null) / 1` throws an exception; `Integer.valueOf(129) / 1` may not be identical to `Integer.valueOf(129)` (as in `first != second`.

Comment: "I mean that a division by one is not necessary, then JIT could optimize this." - Given that you'd probably rarely write code like `a/1` but more `a/x` I'd doubt the JIT would try to "optimize" anything here as it would always have to check for `x` being 1 or not.